# Winter Bash 2018 の帽子リスト

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

[image: Winter Bash 2018 のロゴです]

> 2018年の終わりが [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) にも近づいています…つまり…帽子の季節です！サイトを利用するともらえる素敵な帽子をかぶって、年越しを暖かく楽しく過ごしましょう。帽子は1月2日には回収されてしま‌​‌​います。お早目に！
>
> https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/

毎年 Stack Exchange では、年末に **Winter Bash** というイベントが開催されます。Winter Bash では特定の条件を満たすことで**帽子**を手に入れることができます。手に入れた帽子は、期間限定で被ることもできます！

今年の帽子に関して公表されている情報は[こちらから確認できます](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)が、例年シークレットな帽子も存在します。また日本語だと帽子の名前のネタが分かりづらいものも存在します。

Winter Bash をより楽しむため、帽子の情報について教えてください！

#### 参考

- [ハッピー Winter Bash 2018!](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2886/19110) -- スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319838/341401) -- Stack Exchange

Answer (score 0):

### 公開されている帽子

#### Scarf Ace

[image: Scarf Ace]

条件: [「師匠」バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru)を獲得する
背景: スカーフェイス（アルパチーノの映画）

---

#### Glasses With A Number On Top

[image: Glasses With A Number On Top]

条件: 年の変わり目 (1月1日 0:00 UTC ±12h) にチャットで☆をもらう
背景: よくあるニューイヤー眼鏡

---

#### It Ain’t Easy Being Cheesy

[image: It Ain’t Easy Being Cheesy]

条件: 6日間に6つの帽子をかぶる
背景: "馬鹿げたことだが簡単ではない" (スナック菓子「チートス」のスローガン。[参考1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chester_Cheetah), [参考2](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/6786131))、画像はチーズフォンデュがモチーフ

---

#### Six-Cornered Hat

[image: Six-Cornered Hat]

条件: [「復活の呪文」バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)を獲得
背景: ???

---

#### Peacekeeper

[image: Peacekeeper]

条件: 無事に20レビュー
背景: 『ロボコップ』

---

#### Rep Hunter

[image: Rep Hunter]

条件: 1日で5つの承認された回答
背景: Stack Exchange ウェブサイトの信用度アイコン

---

#### Pizza Hat

[image: Pizza Hat]

条件: 承認済みの質問にスコア+3の回答を追加
背景: ピザチェーンの『ピザハット (Pizza Hut)』とのダジャレ

---

#### Red Baron

[image: Red Baron]

条件: -3の質問に回答し、後に+3の質問になり、回答は+5
背景: ???

---

#### Brunhilde

[image: Brunhilde]

条件: 3つ以上のサイトで150点の信用度を獲得
背景: ???

---

#### SO Goes Flapper

[image: SO Goes Flapper]

条件: 長文の回答に打ち勝つ短文の回答で承認を得る
背景: おてんば娘 (1920年台に流行した、女性ファッションや生活スタイルを指すスラング)

---

#### Team Player

[image: Team Player]

条件: [stackoverflow.com/teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) を訪問
背景: ラグビーのヘッドキャップ

---

#### It’s-a me!

[image: It’s-a me!]

条件: 6個のコメントを投稿者による編集の後に削除
背景: 『スーパーマリオブラザーズ』のマリオ

---

#### Still Fresh

[image: Still Fresh]

条件: サイトに登録して6ヶ月以内の新規ユーザーで、信用度を25点以上得た人 (サイトへのアカウント紐づけボーナスも数えます)
背景: Fresh Prince of Bel-Air（ウィルスミスが有名になったsitcom）?

---

#### IDENTIFICATION DIVISION

[image: IDENTIFICATION DIVISION]

条件: [銀バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver)を獲得する
背景: `IDENTIFICATION DIVISION` とは COBOL の用語。帽子は COBOL 開発者[グレース・ホッパー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%BB%E3%83%9B%E3%83%83%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC)から。([詳細](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304409/341401))

---

#### Top(bar) Hat

[image: Top(bar) Hat]

条件: 回答を得る又は回答して信用度を得る
背景: Stack Exchange ウェブサイトのトップバー, 『きかんしゃトーマス』のトップハム・ハット卿

---

#### I’ll Handle It

[image: I’ll Handle It]

条件: 質問をクローズ、編集、再オープン
背景: 英語 "handle" のダジャレ

---

#### Freehand Circle

[image: Freehand Circle]

条件: [「いい回答」バッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer)を獲得 (回答自体は Winter Bash 期間外に投稿されたものでも OK)
背景: 手描きの丸。スクリーンショットを投稿する際には注目して欲しい場所に印をつけて欲しいという話から、[Stack Exchange Network でミームになった](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/341401)。

---

#### Explorer

[image: Explorer]

条件: 投票のない承認された回答
背景: ???

---

#### Gonna Find Out

[image: Gonna Find Out]

条件: 150回投票する
背景: Santa Claus Is Coming to Town の"gonna find out who's naughty or nice"の箇所

---

#### Member of The Hand

[image: Member of The Hand]

条件: 初心者マークのユーザーがメタかメインサイトで投稿して+3
背景: Daredevil

---

#### Silencium

[image: Silencium]

条件: 一週間回答がつかない質問
背景: ???

Answer (score 0):

### シークレット帽子

本当に存在する帽子だけ書くようにしてください。[MSE での投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319840)が参考になります。

追記する際にはスポイラー `>!` で装飾して隠してください。スポイラーの中身はホバー／クリック／タップすることで見ることができます。

#### Retro Fan

[image: Retro Fan]

> 条件: [1年以上経っている投稿 (質問または回答) に投票する](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/conversation/retro-fan)
>  背景: ???

---

#### The Merlin

[image: The Merlin]

> 条件: 「ひらめき」バッジを獲得する
>  背景: マーリンは偽史『ブリタニア列王史』に登場する魔術師

---

#### James Bond

[image: James Bond]

> 条件: コメントが 0 個の質問にコメントが 0 個の回答をし、その回答が最低 +7 のスコアを得る
>  背景: 『007』

---

#### Waffles

[image: Waffles]

> 条件: 質問や回答に合計15個のコメントをする
>  背景: Stack Exchange networkで[古くから流行りのミーム](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480/295232)。そして美味しい。

---

#### Rubber Ducky

[image: Rubber Ducky]

> 条件: 「質問する」ページで「破棄」ボタンを使う
>  背景: ???

---

#### Sun Wukong

[image: Sun Wukong]

> 条件: メタサイトに、最低 5 つの upvote と 5 つの downvote を得た質問を投稿する。Meta Stack Exchange でも OK。
>  背景: "評価が分かれる、議論の的となる" ([Metaでのアイデアが元ネタ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305506/403540))。

---

#### Clean-Up Duty

[image: Clean-Up Duty]

---

#### Propel Thyself

[image: Propel Thyself]

> 条件: [1つのサイトで他に3つのシークレット帽子を得る](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86686/conversation/propel-thyself-test)
>  背景: ???