# ハッピー Winter Bash 2018!

Tags: サポート, winter-bash

世界には沢山の恒例行事があります。例えば、[トマト](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Tomatina)や[オレンジ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Oranges) を投げるフェスティバルや、[お猿のビュッフェ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_Buffet_Festival)、そして[チーズ転がし](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooper%27s_Hill_Cheese-Rolling_and_Wake)祭り。このような創造性が溢れる行事の中、スタック・オーバーフローにも毎年恒例のイベントがあります。そう、**Winter Bash** です！

[image: Image of Winter Bash 2018]

今年は Winter Bash 7年目の帽子への愛を記念して、ユーザーのみなさんと一緒に *一本の毛糸のようにつながること*を試みたいと思います。今年は本物の毛糸を無駄にせずにクリエイティブになる方法を追加しました。[Winter Bash の開催期間は](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)2018年12月12日から2019年1月1日までです！

Winter Bash の参加サイトで[特定のチャレンジ](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)をクリアし、特別な帽子を獲得してください！獲得した帽子をあなたのアバターにかぶらせずにアンロックすることも可能です。今年は帽子のセレクションに少し変更を加え、[コミュニティからのアイデア](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help)を取り入れました！帽子を獲得できる条件もいくつかリフレッシュされましたので、どうぞ見つけてみてください。

チャレンジが完了すると、帽子のアイコンがあなたのプロフィールに表示されます：

[image: Image of hat icon in profile]

帽子をクリックすると帽子ボックスが開きます：

[image: Image of hat rack]

帽子を選ぶと同時に、アバターにフィットするよう位置・サイズを調整することもできます：

[image: Image of resize tool]

以上です！帽子をたくさん集めて、コレクションをどうぞ自慢してください 。1週間毎日違う帽子をかぶってみようかなウィーク、とするのも楽しいかもしれません。帽子を獲得すればすぐにかぶることができます。なお、2019年1月2日に全ての帽子はお掃除や修理のために倉庫へ戻ってしまうので、その点はどうぞご注意ください。

さぁ、私たちの伝統行事を楽しみましょう！

---

Many thanks to [@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki) for the translation!

Comment: 獲得できる帽子の一覧は、[こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2881/19110)へどうぞ。