# 誰が一番クールに帽子を着こなしている？

Tags: 討議, winter-bash

このメタ質問は @Nicolas Chabanovsky さんの草稿を元に和訳しました。
Thank you for [@Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/78/nicolas-chabanovsky) !
A lot of thanks to [@cubick](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick) for the translation!

---

帽子を被っているユーザーがいることに気が付きましたか？プロフィール画像で帽子をエレガントに、または愉快に着こなしているのは誰でしょう？
あなたが一番お気に入りの帽子を被ったプロフィール画像をスクリーンショットで保存し、この質問への回答としてぜひ投稿してみてください！

例として、いくつか私が気に入ったユーザーのプロフィール画像をご紹介します！ ^_^

[image: nekketsuuu]
[image: Liamovwv]
[image: kabichan]

**参考**

- [Winter Bash 2018 の帽子リスト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2881/3060)
- [ハッピー Winter Bash 2018!](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2886/3060)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Comment: おおっと、バレてしまいましたか

Answer (score 2):

[image: shingo.nakanishiさん]