# クールな帽子セレクション 2019

Tags: 討議, winter-bash

[昨年に引き続き](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2896/14055)、帽子のお洒落さんを見かけたらどうぞ回答欄にシェアしてください。

今年のWinter Bashは、一歩先を行くこちらの着こなしでスタートしました。
[image: Tokyo 2020]

参考：

- [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 の帽子リスト ❄️](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3144/14055)  -スタック・オーバーフロー
- [Show off your hats! (2019 edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340171/314875)  -Stack Exchange

Answer (score 2):

[image: コンテンポラリーアート顔負けの]

[image: あまりお見かけしなかった帽子かと]

[image: こちらにも♡が]

[image: さりげない着こなし発見]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

最初目にしたとき、`八つ墓村`を連想しました。
大きいアイコンではあまり感じませんが、小さいアイコンでは今も連想します。
茶化しているわけではありません、クールです！！！

[image: nekketsuuu]

Answer (score 1):

[image: たくさんの愛♡ (diversity effect)]

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]