# Silenciumの翻訳が間違っている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, winter-bash

[Winter Bash 2019](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/) の帽子 "Silencium" の説明文の翻訳が間違っています。

- 原文：question with no flags for a week
- 現在の和訳：一週間回答がつかない質問
- 和訳修正案：一週間通報されなかった質問

[Winter Bash 2018 のとき](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/19110)の "Silencium" の説明文は確かに「一週間回答がつかない質問」だったのですが、2019 で条件が変わり、翻訳が追従できていないようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

以下のように修正されましたことを確認いたしました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]